# Ubuntu 20.04 Freezes When Running Virtualization

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, freeze

Ubuntu 20.04 freezes whenever I am running any sort of virtualization software. Itll be running fine and then all of a sudden the host just freezes. Nothing is active - keyboard, mouse. The video stops playing, audio just keeps on looping through the last word that was said. I've waited 5 mins and it just never recovers.

Ive tried VirtualBox, VMWare and even GNOME Boxes with the same result.

I'm running Nvidia GEforce GTX 1060 3GB.

I picked up these from the log:

```
11:16:55 AM systemd-udevd: /etc/udev/rules.d/60-brother-libsane-type1-inst.rules:14 Invalid key 'SYSFS'
11:16:55 AM kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
```

Updated for further info request

`free -h` output - I am not running the VM now since I don't want a crash:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.6Gi        11Gi        72Mi       2.6Gi        13Gi
Swap:          18Gi          0B        18Gi
```

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

I have assigned 8 GBs of RAM to the guest and 4 CPUs. I do have the same set up under Windows ( dual boot ) on the same system which runs smooth.

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
F.25
```

```
$ neofetch
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64 
Host: OMEN by HP Obelisk Desktop 875 
Kernel: 5.4.0-33-generic 
Packages: 2352 (dpkg), 12 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.16 
Resolution: 1680x1050, 1680x1050 
GNOME 
Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-8700 (12) @ 4.600GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB 
Memory: 1766MiB / 15891MiB
```

```
$ sudo grep -i swap /etc/fstab
# swap was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=ce9111f7-159f-4b0f-a64e-dab27666db50 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

NVIDIA info:

```
$ dpkg -l \*nvidia\* | grep ii
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-440:amd64         440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-440             440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:amd64      440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:i386       440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-440:amd64       440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-440:i386        440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-440:amd64       440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-440:i386        440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-440:amd64        440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-440:amd64         440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386          440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-440:amd64           440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-440:i386            440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-440:amd64         440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386          440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-440         440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-440                  440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-440                440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-440         440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-440         440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                     0.8.14                        all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                  440.64-0ubuntu1               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-440                 440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440    440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: AMI
       physical id: 0
       version: F.25
       date: 11/19/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3c
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: HP26D4U6D8ME-16X
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0
          serial: EF02EDAB
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 46
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 47
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1536KiB
       capacity: 1536KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 48
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 12MiB
       capacity: 12MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a3516000-a3517fff memory:a351f000-a351ffff
```

```
$ dpkg -l *virtualbox*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                           Version                   Architecture Description
+++-==============================-=========================-============-=====================================================
rc  virtualbox                     6.1.6-dfsg-1              amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
un  virtualbox-2.0                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-2.1                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-2.2                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.0                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.1                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.2                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.0                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.1                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.2                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.3                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.0                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.1                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.2                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-6.0                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-6.1                 6.1.10-138449~Ubuntu~eoan amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
un  virtualbox-dkms                <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-dkms          <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-modules       <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-modules             <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-ose                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
rc  virtualbox-qt                  6.1.6-dfsg-1              amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
un  virtualbox-source              <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. How much memory and CPU have you assigned to the guest?

Comment: For the decoding message, try `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`.

Comment: For the udev message, assure that you've got the latest Brother printer/scanner software installed.

Comment: Lastly, show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer. Tell me what version Nvidia driver you have.

Comment: For your VM, try setting the RAM=2048, and CPU=2.

Comment: @heynnema what does "sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)" do ?

I have updated info that you have requested

Comment: For the `Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed` error, that command rebuilds the ramdisk file that's used at that time. Look in /boot for the initrd.img file before and after the command and note if the file size changes.

Comment: @heynnema just ran the VM with RAM=2048 and 2 CPU and it froze as soon as I ran GNOME software update on Fedora. Ive noticed the same when Ive run update via pamac on Manjaro.

Its sitting frozen right.....we can probably get the best logs if you can tell me where to get em post reboot.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

OMEN by HP Obelisk Desktop 875

You have BIOS F.25.

<strike>There's a newer BIOS available, F.51, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/omen-by-hp-875-0000-obelisk-desktop-pc-series/23302709).</strike> See [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/omen-by-hp-875-0000-obelisk-desktop-pc-series/23302709/model/23574497?sku=4NM65AA).

**Note**: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model # variation.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

---

**initrd.img**

For the `Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed` message, rebuild your ramdisk with `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`.

Look in /boot for the initrd.img file before and after the command and note if the file size changes.

---

**VM**

Your RAM and CPU settings for the VM are unnecessarily high. Set them to RAM=2048 and CPU=2.

---

**swap**

For 16 RAM host RAM, unless you're hibernating, a 18G swap is unnecessary. Downsize it to 4G and you should be fine.

In looking at /etc/fstab, it shows that you're using a swap partition. To reduce the size of swap, you'd have to edit the partition size and reinitialize the swap.

Probably easier to change to using a /swapfile, and deleting the current swap partition.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Change this line in /etc/fstab...

From:

```
UUID=ce9111f7-159f-4b0f-a64e-dab27666db50 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

To this:

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

Then reboot and verify proper operation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109010/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-ubuntu-20-04-freezes-when-running-virtualizatio).